# Getting error Invalid state change requested in Magento2.2.6

Tags: magento2

When I am placing order by my payment gateway I am getting error **Invalid state change requested.** I debug the core code and found that is error is coming from plugin used by core classes. i.e **Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Plugin\AccessChangeQuoteControl** which is not exist in previous version of magento2 (i.e before Magento2.2) . Have anyone idea what is purpose of this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at the [source-code](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository/Plugin/AccessChangeQuoteControl.php):

> Checks if change quote's customer id is allowed for current user.

Comment: I found beforeSave() function but, How to check "if change quote's customer id is allowed for current user"?

Comment: on guest check out it's working but when user can login and trying to place order at that time this error occur.

Comment: i don't get what you mean. the plugin does that for you

Comment: I found this in source code but how can I debug this error? so I can get a solution.

Comment: it depends on your code. the plugin is definitly not the problem. it's essential for security

Comment: OK, I think I need to pass Authentication token, but i don't know where i have to put it and on which file.